# Difference between Context.openFileInput() and using the Java.IO classes

Tags: java, android, api, io

What is the difference between the Context IO API (openFileInput and openFileOutput) and using Java's IO API on Context.getFilesDir?

Comment: what happened when you googled for that? :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much. For example, here is the implementation of `openFileInput()` [from `ContextImpl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java) (the base implementation of `Context`):

```
@Override
public FileInputStream openFileInput(String name)
  throws FileNotFoundException {
  File f = makeFilename(getFilesDir(), name);
  return new FileInputStream(f);
}
```

where `makeFilename()` is there to yell at you if you have a directory separator in the filename.

Personally, I use `getFilesDir()`, as it is more flexible.